# The company "..." dropdown is not styled

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, companies-page

Looking at a company listing where have the "Create Job Alert" button and the "..." dropdown next to it:

[image]

when clicking the "..." dropdown, there is no styling around the box that pops up:

[image]

There should probably be a shadow or border around this box.

Comment: ...wait, but there **is** a border and a shadow around “Dismiss”.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this! We're actually working on a feature at the moment that adds a few more items in that overflow menu, so we'll fix this styling bug at the same time.